# Mongodb - I have 2 collections `Users` and `Markers` - How do I handle adding the `userid` to new Marker created?

Tags: mongodb

I just have 2 collections right now - `Users` and `Markers`.

`Users` schema is something like this:

```
{
  username: String,
  isVerified: Boolean,
  zipCode: Number
}
```

Each new user that I create in `Users` has an objectId like this:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("588fbd3e39b266783285d573"), 
 "username" : "testuser",
 "isVerified": true,
 "zipCode": 12345
}
```

`Markers` is a collection of Marker objects created by users.  It has some title, description, latLng, etc. However, I want to add the `Users.username` and also a *userid* of some kind.  For this purpose, is it fine to just use the `Users._id`?

I'm fairly new to nosql database design so please bear with me.  Since I am returning `Markers` data to the client side, I need a userid so I can open a user's profile page from it since my API can just use a userId parameter.  But, should I have both `username` and `userid` in each Marker?

** after some reading I've decided to switch to postgres and learn that since my data is relational.  thx for the help

Comment: Assuming that the markers are user specific (which is not exactly clear from your question), you'll be probably better of including them in the user object. Your design looks very "relational databse" so far, which is not the way to use mongo at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your username is unique, you can either have username or userid in your Markers connection. Mongodb does not support foreign keys intrinsically, nor does it support referential integrity. So it will have to be up to you update/delete these references as the data changes.

Comment: Thanks!  Usernames are unique and cannot be changed (for now at least).  Since I am unsure if that will change, will I be making a mistake to use the `_id` of the user?  In my use case, if I am a logged in user, I will create a new marker and I already have my userid (which is the `_id`), so I can just use that as my `userId` when I create a new marker object.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that. Going with _id is almost always a safe bet